# Tornado не принимает запросы

Tags: python, http, cookie, tornado

Есть небольшой сервис на торнадо. Всё работает замечательно на компьютере, но на телефонах (йфон и Андроид) появилась интересная проблема.

На одной страничке есть кнопка от Вконтакте, размещает запись на стену.
После того как кнопку нажмешь - торнадо перестает принимать запросы от мобильного браузера. Просто пусто в логе, в браузере попытка соединения.

На компьютере удалось это повторить только после многодневного мучения кнопки.

Ошибка пропадает при очистке cookies!
Пытаюсь возпроизвести...

Возможно ли что торнадо не может прочесть все заголовки? Ведь до лимита в 4к на куки явно ещё далеко. Как можно исправить торнадо или хотябы найти узкое место?

Comment: поставил nginx, 50x ошибок нет..

Answer (score 2):

Решилось подстройкой MSS на сервере... Считаю что это только workaround, но всё же приведу.

Подстройка MSS выполняется тривиально на iptables.

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --set-mss 1400
```

Дошел до этого решения изучая дампы через wireshark, в дампах были пакеты `SYN`, но не было `ACK`.

Проблему с сетью исключаю потому что ping большими пакетами, проходит без необходимости в фрагментации и потерь. Но похоже Баг где-то в tcp - будем смотреть роутеры.

Comment: если вы нашли решение, и если не хотите его полностью приводить - просто удалите вопрос.

Comment: @PashaPash развернул ответ, сразу это сделать было некогда немножко